# How can I serve subversion from my IIS 7 server?

Tags: svn, iis

I set up subversion on my Windows 2008 server and it works fine locally, but when on a remote machine, I would like to be able to access my repository by using the URL of a website hosted on my server.  Any idea how I can set that up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think Subversion offers any integration into IIS - according to [this 2008 mailing list post](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2008-04/0597.shtml), there aren't even plans - , but when you're on a Windows machine, why not use [VisualSVN](http://visualsvn.com/)?

It builds on a stripped down Apache internally, is set up within minutes, and offers a great, simple interface to managing repos and users.

Comment: @Pekka i have setup visual svn on windows 2008 R2 Server correctly.it works perfectly on local machine. but how can i access it by eclipse check out ? i mean repository url ? thanks

Answer (score 4):

What about using [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)? It's free and very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for IIS. You can just use the svnserve executable included with subversion. You could install it on the same machine as your webserver, and serve both `http://example.com` and `svn://example.com` that way. See the section [svnserve, a Custom Server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) in the excellent subversion book.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what little experience I have with it, svnserve is very limited in some areas: No fine-grained user access control (it's either read, write, or nothing), you need to run a separate instance for each repository etc.

Comment: @Pekka: The fine grained authorization mechanism is the same for svnserve as for apache: an authz file. But there are indeed some disadvantages to svnserve: no choice in the authentication mechanism, no encryption unless tunneled over SSH, no logging and no repository browsing with a webbrowser. OTOH it is much simpler to set up than apache, and the protocol is faster.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I too had the feeling that it's a great lightweight alternative when you don't need all the bells and whistles. On Windows, though, if resources are not an issue, VisualSVN is hard to beat IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion and Apache libraries are tightly integrated with each other and thus it is not possible to get it running under any other Servers.

Consider using CollabNet Subversion Edge - http://collab.net/svnedge

It's a two step installation process and is way better than VisualSVN, IMO.

Comment: Out of interest, why "way better"? Everyone on Windows seems to use VisualSVN by default

Comment: @NickG You may install and find the difference yourself :) Edge has many features that VisualSVN doesn't have. Not to mention, it works on Linux and Solaris too :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the same idea

Recently I came across Rocket SVN http://www.axosoft.com/rocketsvn, it runs directly on IIS