# How to list SVN repos? Ideally in a browser.

Tags: svn

Is there a way I can list all repositories I have on my SVN server?  I've found I can do this using the SVNListParentPath directive for Apache according to the SVN documentation.  However, My SVN server is running IIS on a Windows Server 2003.

Is there any way you can do this?

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that you're running your Subversion repository under IIS and not using `svnserve` or `Apache httpd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is currently any IIS+svn integration.

See these posts:

[how-can-i-serve-subversion-from-my-iis-7server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575647/how-can-i-serve-subversion-from-my-iis-7-server)

[run-svn-repositories-under-iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165540/run-svn-repositories-under-iis)